# How does append work in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I just started learning Lisp and I don't seem to understand the following piece of code:

```
(setf y (loop for x in y
              for z = (something)
              unless (condition for z)
              append z))
```

Where is **z** appended?

Comment: all the z in each iteration are appended and returned as one list...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is appended to an unnamed list to be returned when the loop terminates.  As first approximation, you may think of it as a shorthand for

```
(loop ... append z into result finally (return result))
```

The `append` here is a loop keyword; it's not related to the `append` function, except for sharing the same name --- so it's the [loop](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_a.htm) macro that decides how it works, instead of the `append` function.